# webRTC video chat using Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, webrtc

The code lab explaining webRTC and firestore is not clear enough to me.
https://webrtc.org/getting-started/firebase-rtc-codelab

I am having trouble with the final collectICECandidates step. Where should I be calling this function inside the code and how will I get the local and remote parameters required for the function?

Comment: Several answers below have given [this link](https://github.com/webrtc/FirebaseRTC/blob/solution/public/app.js) as a solution to this problem, and two of them have been deleted by the Review Queue for being too brief. In case the third one is deleted too, I will preserve it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also needed help setting this up. The remotevideo was blank, and I got the 'Got room' in the console when I tried to connect.

To solve this, I found this on the Github's Solution branch: 
https://github.com/webrtc/FirebaseRTC/blob/solution/public/app.js

Comment: Hi Elzie. Can you explain why this was the solution? This link has been given in answers to this question before, and they were deleted for being too brief.

Comment: Hi Halfer. 
I cant really tell why they would've been deleted no. Beats me. 
Just wondering - have you figured out how to make it work with more than 1on1? :)

Comment: Sorry, we're talking at cross-purposes. I don't have this problem myself - I am wondering how this answer can be made more useful for a broad future audience. It seems to be just a link at present, and I wonder if it could be fleshed out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a corrected description in the following fork:
https://github.com/meldaravaniel/FirebaseRTC

And also there's a `solution` branch, were you can download the whole file from.